# Powershell add-member. Add a member that's an ArrayList?

Tags: arrays, powershell

The Powershell "add-member" command is very useful. I use it to add properties to custom objects. Sometimes I set a member as an array to hold multiple objects. Is it possible to add an ArrayList as a member on a custom object?

Imagine a list of articles has properties "index", "title", and "keywords." In Powershell, you could put this code in a loop:

```
for($i = 0; $i -lt 100; $i++) {
    $a = new-object -TypeName PSObject
    $a | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name index -Value $i
    $a | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name title -Value "Article $i"
    $a | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name keywords -Value @()
    $articles += $a
}
```

You'd end up with an array, $articles, of Article objects, each with members index, title, and keywords. Furthermore, the keywords member is an array that can have multiple entries:

```
$articles[2].keywords += "Stack Exchange", "Powershell", "ArrayLists"
$articles[2].keywords[2]
Powershell
```

This meets most of my needs, but I just don't like dealing with arrays. ArrayLists are just easier to work with, if only because

```
$arrayList1.remove("value")
```

is so much more intuitive than

```
$array1 = $array1 |? {$_ new "value"}
```

Is there a way with Add-Member to add an ArrayList as a member? Or am I stuck with arrays? If Powershell doesn't support thi snatively, could I pop in some C# code to make a new class with an ArrayList as a member?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$arr = @("one","two","three")
$arr.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                       
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                       
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array   

$a = new-object -TypeName PSObject 
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$arrList=$arr
$a | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ArrayList -value $arrlist

$a.ArrayList

one
two
three

$a.ArrayList.remove("one")
$a.ArrayList

two
three
```

To add a blank ArrayList to your custom object just use

```
$a | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ArrayList -value (New-object System.Collections.Arraylist)
```

Comment: Oh. So...create the object in a separate variable ($arrList in the example above). Then set that variable as the value of the NoteProperty in Add-Member. Do I have that right?

Comment: Following that logic...could I then add any "new-object" I want as a member of another object?

Comment: Yea, there are no limitations to what objects can be added as a NoteProperty to custom objects, that I know of. And no you don't have to create a seperate variable, sorry I didn't make that clear, it was just an example. Updated..

Comment: A side note on NoteProperties... if you are using a newer version of PS (v3 or higher I think) NotePropertyName and NotePropertyValue are the first and second parameters if that's all you put for a piped object, so it becomes: `$variable | Add-Member <Name> <Value>`, which makes it nice and short. So something like: `$MyObject | Add-Member "Keywords" (New-object System.Collections.Arraylist)` and you're all set!

Comment: @MichaelCornn There's nothing special whatsoever about how you add an ArrayList as a NoteProperty as opposed to any other type. If you supply an ArrayList as the **-Value** argument, then the object will have an ArrayList property. That's all there is to it. If you have an array **$arr**, you can simply cast it as an ArrayList and provide it as the **-Value** argument, no need for a new variable. He just broke it up for clarity. There's no special process. This works as well: `$object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ArrayList -value ([System.Collections.ArrayList]$arr)`.

Answer (score 5):

I find all this Add-Member stuff to be confusing for data only. In powershell 3, you can just make an object from a hashtable, and use a little thing I learned from a [blog](http://www.jonathanmedd.net/2014/01/adding-and-removing-items-from-a-powershell-array.html) about using Invoke to get a Collection typed object:

```
$myObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
        index = $idx;
        title = $title;
        keywords = {@()}.Invoke()
    }

$myObject.keywords.Add("foo")
$myObject.keywords.Add("bar")

Write-Host "Original"
$myObject.keywords
Write-Host

Write-Host "New:"
[void]$myObject.keywords.Remove("foo")
$myObject.keywords
Write-Host

Original
foo
bar

New:
bar
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```
$a | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ArrayList -value (New-object System.Collections.Arraylist)
```

All member arraylist for `$a` have the same Array. Because I suppose is a pointer, so:

```
$a | % {Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ArrayList -value (New-object System.Collections.Arraylist)}
```

Each element of `$a` has its own arraylist